# JMeter HTTP Request Slow Response

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I am using JMeter to perform load testing on HTTPS site. I created script using Blazemeter Script Recorder Manually, I am able to launch and login to website very efficiently. when I play script HTTP Request is working very slow. It take long time to initiate and complete each request as shown below in image.

**1st Request:**

[image]

Second Request:

[image]

I have created **only one thread** as mentioned below in the image

[image]

I will be thankful to you for your help in this regard as i am facing too much delay in each Http Request

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can efficiently troubleshoot your network issues by looking into these 2 screenshots, I can only state that [well-behaved JMeter script produces almost the same response times as the real browser does](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) (actually a little bit less because JMeter doesn't really render the response)

If you want to have the "real" time from your browser either use a "clean" session by removing all browsing history, especially [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) or disable the caching in your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and compare with the `load time` metric:

[image]

What I can tell by looking at your screenshots is that you have very high [Connect Time](https://varvy.com/performance/tcp-connection-time.html) values:

1. For first request it takes 1 second out of 2.6 seconds to establish the connection
2. For second request it takes 900 milliseconds out of 1200 milliseconds to establish the connection

So if you are in Australia and trying to test a server which is located in northern Canada - the only solution would be moving JMeter geographically closer, otherwise contact your network administrator/ISP/etc. and ask them, not us.

You can get debugging information on Java network stack by adding the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
javax.net.debug=all
```